# How to optimize this mysql query? Runs slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using a database that, imho, wasn't designed well, but maybe it's just me not understanding it. Anyways, I have a query that pulls the correct information, but it is really slowing down my php script. I was hoping someone could take a look at this and let me know if nesting queries to this depth is bad, and whether or not there is a way to simplify the query from the relationships depicted in the sql statement below.

```
SELECT name 
FROM groups 
WHERE id = (SELECT DISTINCT immediateparentid 
            FROM cachedgroupmembers 
            WHERE groupid = (SELECT  g.id AS AdminCc
                             FROM Tickets t, groups g  
                             WHERE t.Id = 124 AND t.id = g.instance AND g.type = 'AdminCc')
                             AND immediateparentid <> (SELECT  g.id AS AdminCc
                                                       FROM Tickets t, groups g  
                                                       WHERE t.Id = 124 AND t.id = g.instance AND g.type = 'AdminCc'))
```

Please help

**Update:**

Here is the output from using Explain
[image: Explain]

You may need to right click and select "View Image" for the text to be clear.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: do you have indexes on the relevant fields? that's the first thing you should be checking before you even think about changing the query.

Comment: I would recommend requesting the query plan from the database to see what exactly is taking long. One cannot simply optimize looking at the query alone, the data that it operates on matters as well.

Comment: Are you sure you can't use `JOIN`s?

Comment: Can you explain what it is that this query does?  Perhaps there is a much simpler design that can do the same thing.

Comment: I updated the question with the output of Explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you can eliminate one sub-select.

```
SELECT name 
FROM groups 
WHERE id = (
    SELECT DISTINCT immediateparentid 
    FROM cachedgroupmembers 
    WHERE groupid = (
        SELECT g.id 
        FROM Tickets t, groups g
        WHERE t.Id = 124 AND t.id = g.instance AND g.type = 'AdminCc'
    ) AND immediateparentid != groupid
)
```

Comment: @veryConfused as +njk suggests, JOIN's could eliminate the need for (all?) sub-selects, but without knowing the table structure it's hard to provide more help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm much more used to PL/SQL on Oracle but I'll give it a try.

1. Get rid of aliases, you don't need them here.
2. Make sure columns used in the `where` clause are indexed (`t.Id` and `g.type`).
3. Don't know if MySQL indexes foreign keys by default but worth the check.

You can shorten your SQL code like that:

```
SELECT name 
FROM groups 
WHERE id = (
    SELECT DISTINCT immediateparentid 
    FROM cachedgroupmembers 
    WHERE groupid = (
        SELECT g.id 
        FROM Tickets t, groups g
        WHERE t.Id = 124 AND t.id = g.instance AND g.type = 'AdminCc'
   ) AND immediateparentid != groupid
)
```

or:

```
 SELECT name 
    FROM groups 
    WHERE id = (
        SELECT DISTINCT immediateparentid 
        FROM cachedgroupmembers 
        WHERE groupid = (
            SELECT g.id 
            FROM Tickets t inner join groups g on t.id = g.instance
            WHERE t.Id = 124 AND g.type = 'AdminCc'
 ) AND immediateparentid != groupid
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your tickets table is big you may consider a temp table instead of querying it twice